# Fix permission error for deleting custom post from front-end?

Tags: custom-post-types, permissions

I need both Admin and Editor role users to be able to delete a custom post type from the front-end.  I found the code to create a post delete link, but whenever either role tries to delete there is an error:

Forbidden  You don't have permission to access /wp-admin/post.php on this server.

Any ideas?  Is it because this is a custom post type?  The post delete code is included below.

In function.php:

```
function wp_delete_post_link($link = 'Delete This', $before = '', $after = '')
{
global $post;
if ( $post->post_type == 'page' ) {
if ( !current_user_can( 'edit_page', $post->ID ) )
return;
} else {
if ( !current_user_can( 'edit_post', $post->ID ) )
return;
}
$link = "<a onclick=\"return confirm('Are you SURE you want to delete this post/page?')\" href='" . wp_nonce_url( get_bloginfo('url') . "/wp-admin/post.php?action=delete&amp;post=" . $post->ID, 'delete-post_' . $post->ID) . "'>".$link."</a>";
echo $before . $link . $after;
}
```

Inserted into page:

```
<?php wp_delete_post_link('Delete', ' <strong class="delete">', '</strong> ') ?>
```

Comment: That looks like a server error outside of WordPress - are you sure the URL is valid & points to the correct location of `wp-admin/post.php`?

Answer (score 2):

Here you go, this creates a Delete Post link that only appears to the user if they are both logged in and the author of the post. When the link is clicked, they get a js confirmation asking them if they're sure, which once clicked will delete the post. And it does work with Custom Post Types, tested it myself.

```
<?php if ($post->post_author == $current_user->ID) { ?><p><a onclick="return confirm('Are you SURE you want to delete this post?')" href="<?php echo get_delete_post_link( $post->ID ) ?>">Delete post</a></p><?php } ?>
```